# How do I use the uniform property of quotient spaces to establish a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Let an annulus be ${1\leq x^2+y^2\leq4}$ and $I^2=[0,1]^2$.

The annulus is given the equivalence relation $(x,y)$~$(x',y')$ and $(x',y')$~$(2x,2y)$ if $x^2+y^2=1$

While $I^2$ is given the following equivalence relation: $(x,y)$~$(x',y')$ and $(0,y)$~$(1,y')$ and $(x,1)$~$(x',0)$ if $0\leq x,y \leq 1$

I tried to establish homeomorphisms between the quotient spaces and the torus but that method seems to be too long and tedious. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider expressing the annulus as $I \times S^1$: e.g. via $\varphi: [1,2] \times S^1 \rightarrow A$ given by $\varphi(r, \theta) = (r cos \theta, r sin \theta)$. Then the relation on the annulus is given by identifying the endpoints of $[1,2]$, giving something homeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^1$.

That gives one homeomorphism to the torus. Given that you recognised that the torus was involved I believe you can build the other.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $[1,2]$x$[0,2\pi]$

Comment: The important thing is to recognise why the annulus is an interval times a circle.